# How to use JavaScript or jQuery to wrap a range (from selection) in a web page into a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I need to find a way to wrap some range into a specific tag using javascript or jQuery.

for example:

```
<p> hey how are you? </p>
<p> I am good! </p>
```

then use a javascript code in the console to get:

```
<p> hey <mytag> how are you? </p>
<p> I am </mytag> good! </p>
```

I know how to get a range from a selection, but I need to find a way to wrap this range.

Thank You!

Comment: Your required HTML is not valid.

Comment: Fort what purpose do you need this range?

Comment: If You start tag in <p> tag than also you have to close with in same <p> tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can tag the wanted area like this:

**HTML**

```
<p> hey how are you? </p>
<p> I am good! </p>

<p> hey <span class="mytag"> how are you? </span></p>
<p><span class="mytag">I am</span> </mytag> good! </p>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function() {
    var test = '';
    $('.mytag').each(function (index) {
        test += $(this).text();
    });
    //use test as you want
});
```